# Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.dll, when using TransactionScope

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle

I call a stored procedure on Oracle, using a TransactionScope, and the IIS express crashes.

If I remove the transaction scope, works like a charm.

```cs
    using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        ·
        · here I call the SP
        ·
        transactionScope.Complete();
    }
```

The output console shows a bunch of exceptions, but I doubt they have anything to do with the real issue.

Here is the output: https://pastebin.com/EAPPy53p

Comment: I haven't made any change to my code or my configuration, but this problem is not happenning anymore, I think it had something to do with the VPN I use to connect to this database. Because in some random ocassions I had this error too, ORA-12571: TNS:packet writer failure.